# Failing to export variable defined in function to another concurrently-ran JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been reading different posts on Google and SO, but I just can't figure out why this does not work.

There are 2 HTML and 2 JS files involved in this case (explanation given below in words after the code chunks).

1) index.html

```
<div id="center">
  <img id="logo" src="../img/logowshadow.png" alt="logo">
  <p id="para">Get your google slides!</p>

  <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
  <button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Sign in</button>
  <button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>
</div>

<script src="../js/homePage.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
  onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
  onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

2) homePage.js

```
var apiKey = 'AIzaSyCSjg3rrx6Obl4ngZsDlFlV4degUJSMvbw';
var discoveryDocs = ["https://slides.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"];
var clientId = '408869653199-ruoft30vmoqrgpku3us3qd2leb3k6tp1.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');
var user;
var authResponse;
var oauthToken;
var pickerApiLoaded = false;
var chosenPresentation = null;

function handleClientLoad() {
    // Load the API client and auth2 library
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
    //Load the Picker API
    gapi.load('picker', onPickerApiLoad);
}

function initClient() {
    gapi.auth2.init({
        apiKey: apiKey,
        discoveryDocs: discoveryDocs,
        clientId: clientId,
        scope: scopes
    }).then(function () {
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
      // Set the current Google User
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.listen(updateUser);
      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
      signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
    });
}

// Callback to make sure that the Picker API has loaded
function onPickerApiLoad() {
  pickerApiLoaded = true;
  createPicker();
}

// Store the current Google user
function updateUser(gUser) {
  user = gUser;
  updateToken();
}

// Store the access token
function updateToken() {
  authResponse = user.getAuthResponse(true);
  oauthToken = authResponse.access_token;
}

function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
      signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
      createPicker();
    } else {
      authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
      signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
}
function handleSignoutClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
}

// Create and render a Picker object for picking user slides
function createPicker() {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
      var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
        addView(google.picker.ViewId.PRESENTATIONS).
        setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
        setDeveloperKey(apiKey).
        setCallback(pickerCallback).
        build();
      picker.setVisible(true);
    }
}

// Callback implementation
function pickerCallback(data) {
      var url = 'nothing';
      if(data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL].replace('edit', 'present');
        var item_name = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        alert('You picked ' + item_name);
        //export the chosen presentation for use in mobileControl.js
        chosenPresentation = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        alert("chosen: " + chosenPresentation);
        exports.chosenPresentation = chosenPresentation;
        window.location.replace(url);
    }
}
```

3) mobile.html

```
<div id="instructions">
    <p>Swipe <b>left</b> to go to the previous slide.</p>

    <p>Swipe <b>right</b> to go to the next slide.</p>
</div>

<script src="../js/mobileControl.js"></script>
```

and 4) mobileControl.js

```
alert("Loaded the JavaScript!"); //Shows up

var m = require('./homePage.js');
alert("imported"); //Does not show up
alert(m.chosenPresentation); //Does not show up
```

To put in words what my code is trying to achieve: users will be able to sign in to their google accounts, and select a set of Presentation found on their Google drive. I want to pass the Presentation ID on from `homePage.js` to `mobileControl.js`, and I attempted to do so using Node's `exports`. I suspect that it is not working because both scripts are run 'at the same time' (index.html is meant to run on the computer, while mobile.html runs on a mobile device...concurrently). But I am not sure if I am right in identifying the cause, and if so, is there a way to export the variable from within the function after it has been defined? Perhaps I should detect it when the slide has been selected, and only load `mobilePage.js` after everything in `homePage.js` has ran?

My apologies for the long read, but my previous attempt at diluting the example obviously failed miserably so...

Update: user @vsenko is totally right in saying that I have mixed up client-side programming and server-side programming, so do read up more on this if you are facing the same issue as me

Comment: In your first example, you're never calling `onInit` so your module is never exported. In your second example, you never export anything at all. It looks like you need to read the docs on exporting modules. Have you looked at the console for errors - in the second if you get no alert then there is almost certainly a JS error

Comment: That is why we ask for the *real* code not some contrived example of what you think it represents. [mcve]

Comment: Understood. I have done a complete overhaul of the post, and I hope it makes a lot more sense now! Thanks for the tip

Comment: That's a lot of code. Is this really minimal? I.e. is every single line required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @melpomene for homePage.js I would love to cut it down but the functions call each other once the first one (handleClientLoad()) has been called...but if it helps, I have tested it, and everything up till when I started experimenting with exports has been working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are trying to load .js files with NodeJS specific API (RequireJS API to precise) directly on the web page. This is not going to work because browsers do not implement it natively. To utilize this API you will have to use a preprocessor (Webpack, Browserify or something else).

Other apparent problem with your approach is that you assume that it is possible to transfer data between different devices using something that look like NodeJS modules. But it is not possible, you will have transfer data over the network between your devices directly or though your server.

Comment: which part are you referring to when you say "you are trying to load .js files with NodeJS specific API (RequireJS API to precise) directly on the web page."? Also, I mean to transfer data between different JS files in the same project (if that makes any difference :/)

Comment: For example `var m = require('./homePage.js');` in mobileControl.js loaded by mobile.html. There is no way this is going to work without preprocessing.

Comment: It really matters where the files are run. If they are run by different processes you will definitely need network communications (or inter process communications).

Comment: under what circumstance would preprocessing not be required then? All the examples I've seen so far seem to export with ease, so I was not aware of this. Thanks for taking the time to read the long post

Comment: It really matters where are you going to run JS code - in the web browser or using NodeJS (it is OK to load modules using `require()` in NodeJS). Your question is tagged with node.js tag, but code samples you provided are about web browsers and it confuses a lot!

Comment: I see...I will try again next week, thanks for the invaluable suggestion